# ReactDOM issue: Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactDOM'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-dom

I just restarted my computer and now when I try to run my React project locally I get this error. Before restarting I was able to work on my project just fine. I tried removing my node_modules folder and npm installing again, still not working. Anybody have any ideas what my problem could be? Here is my package.json and webpack.config:

package.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "== README",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
  "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Stefan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  "babel-core": "6.18.2",
  "babel-loader": "6.2.7",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "6.18.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
  "css-loader": "0.26.1",
  "file-loader": "0.9.0",
  "less": "2.3.1",
  "less-loader": "2.2.3",
  "react": "15.4.1",
  "react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.1",
  "react-dom": "15.3.2",
  "react-fontawesome": "1.5.0",
  "react-redux": "4.4.5",
  "react-router": "3.0.0",
  "redux": "3.6.0",
  "style-loader": "0.13.1",
  "url-loader": "0.5.7",
  "webpack": "1.13.3"
  }
}
```

webpack.config:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./frontend/app.jsx",
  output: {
    path: "app/assets/javascripts",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/assets/"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    },{
        test: /\.node$/,
        loader: "node-loader"
    },{
      test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
    }, {
      test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
    }, {
      test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
    }, {
      test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: "file"
    }, {
      test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
    }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
};
```

Comment: Try updating all the react packages to the latest version. E.g. the latest version of `react-dom` is `15.4.1`.

Comment: Yep that fixed it. Thanks for the help Felix!